# Проблема с адаптивностью не работает media запрос

Tags: html, css, css-grid

http://robloxseller.ru/
При уменьшении экрана (830px) футер должен делится на 2 колонки, а потом на 4, но он даже на 2 не делится при 830px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
.footer-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

при этом классы указаны верно, но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML Вы подключаете файл стилей `footer.css` после файла стилей `media.css`, тем самым переопределяя правила, заданные в файле `media.css`. Поставьте подключение файла `media.css` самым последним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. 
P.S Сколько всего я не знаю...

Comment: @WebStud, если ответ помог, можете пометить его решением. Скриншот галочки отметки: bit.ly/2Hss3VA

Comment: Да, конечно, забыл случайно)